# Datatables - Why my page only one when I have 14 total records

Tags: php, datatables

I have 14 in records and 10 display, IDK why I have only page 1

this is my request:
https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/31967/why-my-datatables-serverside-only-have-1-page

[image]

and this is the result of the `"ajax_files/all_phone_numbers.php"`

```
{
    "sEcho": 0,
    "iTotalRecords": "14",
    "iTotalDisplayRecords": 10,
    "aaData": [
        [
            "13863202227",
            ""
        ],
        [
            "13864790508",
            ""
        ],
        [
            "13865174009",
            ""
        ],
        [
            "14073308841",
            ""
        ],
        [
            "14073884953",
            ""
        ],
        [
            "14074500122",
            ""
        ],
        [
            "14075625408",
            ""
        ],
        [
            "14076177154",
            ""
        ],
        [
            "14076688983",
            ""
        ],
        [
            "14077068252",
            ""
        ]
    ]
}
```

**EDIT1**

this is my `all_phone_numbers.php` php file and I'm using MSSQL PDO : http://codepad.org/VdqNDQhx

Comment: All down but nine; set 'em up on the other alley, pard.

Comment: what? I don't understand it

Comment: That's what I mean; that's why I invoked the nigh-on-to inimitable Scotty Briggs of "Roughing It" fame.

Comment: Your AJAX result says that there are only 10 entries to show, so no second page is needed: `"iTotalDisplayRecords": 10,`. Change your server-side code accordingly.

Comment: @Raidri check my edit... check if there is wrong on my server-side...

Comment: It looks like you do filtering and paging before you calculate your `$iFilteredTotal` count, but I can't say how to fix that since I don't know much about PHP. (Adding PHP tag to question to maybe get some experts to come by.)

Comment: Please show the datatables initialisation code.